# jQuery works on Chrome, Firefox, IE but not on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, cross-browser

This code works in computer browsers but it does not work on iPhone. I will be very happy if you can see and tell me the problem. What can the reason be?

```
<ol style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display:inline-block" id="update" class="timeline">
<form id="begenform" action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="feedid" value="<?php echo $feed[$i]['i']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['u']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="i" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
<?php if(!empty($liked['u']))echo"<span style='color:#cd2122'>Beğendin</span>"; else echo '<input id="begenbutton" type="submit" class="likesubmit" value="Beğen" />'?>
</form></ol>


<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".likesubmit").click(function() 
{
var gideni = $("#i").val();
var userid = $("#userid").val();
var feedid = $("#feedid").val();
var dataString = '&userid='+ userid + '&feedid=' + feedid + '&gideni=' + gideni;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "profilelike.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("ol#update").append(html);
$("span.like").text("Ok");
}
});
return false;
}); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for the "touchstart" and "touchend" events:

```
$('.myElement').bind("touchstart", function(e){alert('Clicked!')} );
```

My implementation:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#begenform').bind('touchstart click', function(e) {

        e.stopPropagation(); 
        e.preventDefault();

        var gideni = $("#i").val();
        var userid = $("#userid").val();
        var feedid = $("#feedid").val();
        var dataString = '&userid='+ userid + '&feedid=' + feedid + '&gideni=' + gideni;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "profilelike.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {

                $("ol#update").append(html);
                $("span.like").text("Ok");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});

</script>

<form id="begenform" method="post" action="#">
    <input id="begenbutton" type="submit" class="likesubmit" value="Beğen" />
</form>
```

For me works fine.
Try it :)

Comment: How can i apply this to my code? Is it like $('.likesubmit').bind("touchstart",click  function() );

Comment: Sure I've add implementation in my response. See it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Code works seperatly but it does not work in my full script.. I dont know why.. Maybe something else in my whole code crash this script for a reason.. I dont know what it can be tho.. When i try your code is a clean sheet it works great but not in my full code.. I will try to find the reason.. I really have no idea why it can be and what causes this..

Comment: Looking for all **"("** and **"{"** characters (opened and closed). Do you have some JS errors in browser console?

Comment: It gives this error:   event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. But when i use it in clean sheet, it works in iphone and still gives this error.. I dont think its about this error.

Comment: Mumble, this is a warning not an error. What is your jQuery version? I've tested the script with **1.10.2** hosted by Google: **http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js**

Comment: i am using that one yes.. Now i started deleting everything from code one by one to find what causes this problem..

Comment: It's a good idea :) ... test a single part of code and you'll find the problem. Good luck!

Comment: I found the reason.. I dont know why but an div id which is "body" was causing the problem.. i changed the name of the div and everything worked.. weird.. but thank you very much for your time..